# Could not instantiate bean class multipart resolver

Tags: java, ajax, spring, multipart

I faced an issue cannot solve error: **Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface.** What could be the problem ?

here is the method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="text_ajax.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView testAjaxMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value="fileArrayBB", required=true) MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

System.out.println("reaches the destination");

}
```

In servlet xml I have initialized the bean:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
    </bean>
```

Thank you for your help.

By the way, spring version: *2.5*